# Please help me to understand the difference between streambuf, stringbuf and stringstream?

Tags: c++

Please someone help me to undersatnd the difference between " streambuf, stringbuf and stringstream".

```
void f1(std::string const& text)
{
     std::stringstream           inStream(text);
    cout<<inStream.str()<<endl;
 }
```

or if I write

```
void f2(std::string const& text)
{
    std::stringbuf           inStream(text);
    cout<<inStream.str()<<endl;
 }
```

Both shows the same result. When should I use stringbuf or stringstream? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

A `stringbuf` is used by a `stringstream`, it provides the buffer for the stream. A `streambuf` is just the base class for a `stringbuf`. What you want is a `stringstream` if you need formatted input/output into/out of the stream (like putting numbers in a string), otherwise you want to continue using a simple `string`. You should never need to bother with the `streambuf` family yourself.

Comment: I have made programs considerably faster by "bothering" with `streambuf`, so I wouldn't say it's never useful.

Answer (score 10):

A `std::stringstream` object contains a `std::stringbuf` object that serves as the underlying data-buffer that the stream operators are operating on.  The `stringbuf` object is basically a wrapper around a string-type ... so you are basically inserting and extracting from a string-type object using the `>>` and `<<` operators through the `stringstream` interface.  A `streambuf` object on the other-hand is the underlying I/O memory buffer being used for file I/O when using either `stdin`, `stdout`, `stderr`, or the `fstream` objects.  If you looked at the standard C-style I/O functions, the different would be like how you must provide a memory buffer to a function like `sprintf` to work, where-as `fprintf` writes to an underlying managed I/O buffer.  In the case of C++, a `stringbuf` object allows you to access the underlying memory buffer for a `stringstream` object.

Answer (score 1):

streambuf is a base class for both stringbuf and stringstream, and streambuf has virtual methods that implementing classes can override to provide specific implementations.  stringstream is a class that contains a stringbuf, and can therefore has slightly different functionality than a stringbuf alone does.

Answer (score 1):

For those of you who are from Java:

- stringbuf => java.nio.ByteBuffer
- streambuf => java.nio.Buffer (abstract, same as streambuf)
- stringstream => java.nio.Channel.newReader(...) + java.nio.Channel.newWriter(...)

I was supprised that class hierarchy of stringbuf, streambuf, stringstream, istringstream, ostringstream, iostream, io_base... were astonishingly same as that of Java Nio classes released around 2003 ~ 2004 (refer to Jdk 1.4 Nio).

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Java, but isn't a `streambuf` more like a `ByteBuffer`? `streambuf` isn't abstract, iirc, and it works very much like a... byte(char) buffer.

Comment: By looking into C++ standard library reference, it states that streambuf is abstract so it cannot be directly instantiated. My apology if im wrong. I couldnt find any public constructor or static initializer method. Also, when I see the overflow and underflow method, it makes me think that streambuf is not only java.nio.Buffer (or ByteBuffer) but also has the characteristic of  java.nio.Charset.CharacterEncoder/Decoder.

Comment: For java, ByteBuffer is important as it's the only bridge to send/receive stream of bytes without copying overhead between kernel and jvm heap memory. But I don't see any benefit that I find in ByteBuffer in stream/stringbuf. I always use std::string to do what java.lang.StringBuilder is required to do.